# Central Limit Theorem Fourier Isometry Confusion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, fourier-analysis, central-limit-theorem

Okay, so I'm trying to understand the proof of the classical CLT. I'm not really a probability guy, so I'll apologize in advance for the analysis-heavy language used.

Statement: If $X_i\in L^1\cap L^2$ independent with constant mean and second moment. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{N}}
$$ converges weakly (in the probabilist sense) to a Gaussian.

Looking at the proof, we show essentially that the Fourier Transform (characteristic function) of a sequence of functions (rvs) $f_n$ converges to the Fourier Transform of a Gaussian at least pointwise.

Now, what confuses me is how we complete the proof. We know that the Fourier Transform is an Isometry on $L^2$, so why don't we use this? The standard proof seems to go through either some sort of approximation-theoretic argument using essentially Schwartz class functions and their density to obtain weak convergence or via something called the continuity theorem. Isn't there a another/easier way using the Fourier Isometry (of $L^2$)? The idea here is of course that isometry somehow means that both spaces have the same topology and thus convergence in either is equivalent to convergence in the other.

I'd appreciate any arguments as to why replacing Schwartz argument with the $L^2$ argument does or does not work! References are of course also appreciated.

Comment: It appears that you are confused about some definitions. What probabilists call as weak convergence is not weak convergence in $L^{2}$. It is weak* convergence in the dual of the space of bounded continuous functions. CLT is concerned with this (i.e. weak*) convergence. Also, in your statement of CLT it is important to assume independence of $X_i$'s.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of these issues and have tried  to make the formulation more clear. I by no means meant weak convergence in $L^2$ but convergence in the sense that 
$$ \int g(Y_n) \to \int g(Y)$$ 
for all bounded continuous $g$. I also added the independence assumption and am sorry for my sloppy formulation - I guess I was a bit excited about getting to the main paragraph.

I would still guess though that $L^2$ convergence implies convergence in measure (proba) and thus convergence in distribution, which is what we want, right?

Comment: Fourier transforms of probability measures are bounded continuous functions and they are not $L^{2}$ functions in general. In CLT one proves only point-wise convergence; it is not possible to prove $L^{2}$ convergence in this theorem because it is not assumed that Fourier transforms belong to $L^{2}$. As far as I can see $L^{2}$ theory of Fourier transforms is of no use in CLT.

Comment: But the random variables are in $L^2$ by assumption I thought? It is my understanding that we assume $X_i \in L^1 \cap L^2$, so in particular the Plancherel Transform ($L^2$ extension of FT) is an isometry of $L^2$. Thus the $\mathcal{F} X_i$ are also in $L^2$.

Comment: I think I see it now. I might have been confusing the Fourier Transform of the RVs with the Fourier Transform of their Laws or something similar. I.e. I'm confusing the quantity:
$$\int X(\omega) e^{it\omega} dP(\omega)$$
with
$$\int e^{itx}f(x)dx$$.